# Jenkins as windows service throw outofmemory

Tags: windows, service, jenkins, out-of-memory

I've installed jenkins as windows service and create job that would invoke ant scripts.
Ant scripts consist of mxmlc compiler that would compile flex applications. While compiling it failed and throws an outofmemory exception. I did adjust the ant_opts for memory allocation but to no avail. But when I try to run jenkins in stand-alone mode the problem won't occur.

Anyone had similar issues I've encountered?

```
Exceptions:
[javac] Compiling 163 source files to ....
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 [copy] Copying 21 files to ....
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file ...
[mxmlc] ...
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file ...
[mxmlc] ...
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file ...
[mxmlc] ...
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file ...
[mxmlc] ...
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3 Plug-in\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
[mxmlc] Error: PermGen space
[mxmlc] 
[mxmlc] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
[mxmlc]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
[mxmlc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
[mxmlc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
[mxmlc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
[mxmlc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[mxmlc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.StandardParserConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.IntegratedParserConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.util.ObjectFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.util.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.util.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.util.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.compiler.config.FileConfigurator.load(FileConfigurator.java:113)
```

Comment: Can you please replicate the exception here?

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Did you manage to fix this? I think it has to do something with 64 bit JRE. mxmlc works only with 32 bit JRE. Problem in my setup is that my Jenkins compile both Java and Flex modules. While Java needs 64 bit JRE, Flex needs 32 bit JRE.

Answer (score 0):

In you're running out of Permgen space, try upping the memory available by adjusting the parameters to the JVM.

The jenkins.jenkins\jenkins.xml contains the service setup for the windows service: Here is a copy of our one.

```
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins continuous integration system.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
  <!--
    if you'd like to run Jenkins with a specific version of Java, specify a full path to java.exe.
    The following value assumes that you have java in your PATH.
  -->
  <executable>java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Hudson\.hudson\jenkins.war" --httpPort=80</arguments>
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>
</service>
```

The **-XX:MaxPermSize=512m** parameter was added last week to solve a problem very similar to yours.